# Is there any difference between probability for a single value of the random variable and PMF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I found a question with a similar title but it did not cover the subject enough I think.
When we study basic probability theory, for discrete random variables we define the function $p_x(x)$  (PMF) known as "Probability Disturbution Function".
$p_X(x) : A_x \rightarrow [0,1]$ where $A_x$ is an event space

So, is for example when we roll a die twice and we are asked to calculate the probability the the sum of the results is 7 **isn't that the same** as to calculate the value of PMF $p_X(X = 7)$ if we choose $X$ to denote the random variable that equals the sum of the results of rolling a die twice?
But if we wanted to calculate the probability of bringing $(3,4)$ with the dice which is a specific event different from $(4,3) | (6,1) | (1,6)$ **then can the PMF answer this question for us?**

But more generally, if we wanted to calculate the probability of the sum of the dice to be in the inverval $[2,7]$ **isn't that the same as calculating**  $p_x( 2 \leq X \leq 7)$

So finally, what is (if thereis) the difference between the terms :
"probability of the event i happens " and $p_x(X= x{i _ {happens}})$"?

Comment: You shouldn't write $p_x(x)$ when you mean $p_X(x).$ There is a reason why one is capital and the other is in lower case: they refer to two different things.

Comment: The notation that you are using is not right. The PMF of a random variable $X$, generally denoted by $p_X$, is a non-negative real-valued function such that $\Pr [X=k]=p_X(k)$. This is all.

Comment: @Masacroso so it is the same with the phrase "find the probability of X=k",isn't it?